# Sublime abre arquivo com codificação EUC-JP

Tags: sublime-text-2, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Quando salvo arquivos com caracteres especiais no Sublime, com UTF-8. Ex:

**Dica de Leitura: De Coração para Coração**

Ele reabre com codificação EUC-JP:

**Dica de Leitura: De Cora巽達o para Cora巽達o**

O que pode ser?

Tenho o plugin ConvertToUTF8, ele converte e salva corretamente, mas ao reabrir, troca a codificação.

Comment: Há a possibilidade de gravar o ficheiro com o UTF-8 BOM (Byte Order Mark)?

Comment: Isso funciona, obrigado.

Comment: Haveria um jeito de corrigir isso apenas usando utf-8?

Comment: O UTF-8 BOM é parte oficial do UTF-8 (embora seja opcional). Quanto ao resto, cabe à aplicação tentar adivinhar a codificação. Não uso Sublime portanto não sei como forçar a aplicação a usar a codificação certa.

Comment: Você pode dar um "File > Reopen File with Encoding", também pode checar nas preferências se essa "EUC-JP" está definida como padrão.

Answer (score 1):

No user settings você poderia setar estes dois parametros:

```
"default_encoding": "UTF-8",
"fallback_encoding": "UTF-8",
```

creio que isto pode resolver seu problema.